# expect not taking ssh arguments in while/for loop

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I'm trying to fetch remote machine details (`dmidecode`) for many hosts using some `expect` command.

Below is the `expect` script which I'm using for this purpose.

```
while read i; do
{
/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
 spawn ssh "root@$i" dmidecode 
 expect "Password:"
 send "xxxx\r";
 interact
 EOF
  }
 done<iplist
```

But here command which is not excecuting on the remote machine. I tried with single, double quotes and caret symbol still no luck.

Here I want to execute remote command as argument like : `ssh <ip> <remote command>`

Please shed me some views, I might be missed some params here, please help me

Comment: The final `EOF` may not be preceded by a space character. I'm not 100% certain that's the only error since I'm not used to `expect`.  The `{ ... }` may be removed in any case.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with shell code only and you don't have to learn the Tcl/Expect language.

Comment: Try adding a `-n` option to the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 2):

One simplification would be to eliminate the buggy and slow shell `while` loop which would also free up `stdin` to be used for `interact`. That is, the input file would instead be passed to and read by TCL code in the `expect` script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $0 iplist-file"
    exit 1
}

set ipfh [open [lindex $argv 0]]

while {[gets $ipfh ip] >= 0} {
    spawn ssh root@$ip dmidecode
    expect "Password:"
    send "Hunter2\r";
    interact
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thrig has a great answer. If you want to stick with bash (even though the while-read loop is extremely slow, and tedious to get right syntax-wise), use a different file descriptor to read from the file and allow expect to hold onto stdin:

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 ip; do
# .................^^^
    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
        spawn ssh "root@$ip" dmidecode 
        expect "Password:"
        send "xxxx\r";
        interact
EOF
done 3< iplist 
# ...^^
```

If the dmidecode command does not require human interaction, change `interact` to `expect eof`